# Saving block execution history

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

Is there a way to save a history of executions of Babel code blocks?
Basically I want to record the block, timestamp, and filename.

Maybe if it's not there, someone knows a similar function that I can hack?
Basically I need a way to get a hold of current selection, timestamp and filename, and a way of appending it to a text file.

Comment: Would [capture mechanisms](http://orgmode.org/manual/Capture.html) do the job ? You'd need to press a few keys (can become one, `f8`, or something) each time you run a block, but you should be able to set up templates that capture all you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here what you can do:

- *advice* a function `org-babel-execute-src-block`
- put results into a buffer, "babel-log" in my example

You can also write results into a log file.

```
(require 'time-stamp)

(defadvice org-babel-execute-src-block (after log-org-babel-execute-src-block activate)
  (org-narrow-to-block)
  (let ((file (buffer-file-name)) (src-block (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))))
    (with-current-buffer "babel-log"
      (insert (concat "file:" file " time:" (time-stamp-string) " block\n" src-block "\n\n")))
    )
  (widen)
  )
```